# Move the window of another program and remove the borders

Tags: vb.net, setparent

I'm working on a project to embed another program inside a Panel.  I got this to work but I can't seem to place the window right inside the form.

Picture:

[image]

I'm using MoveWindow and SetWindowLong with no luck so far.. this is my Onload event;

```
Dim proc As Process = Process.Start("C:\Nexon\MapleStory\MapleStory.exe", "GameLaunching")
proc.WaitForInputIdle()
SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND2, SC_CLOSE, 0)

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
Do
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
Loop Until FindWindow("MaplestoryClass", Nothing)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)

SetWindowLong(Processes(0).MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE)

MoveWindow(Processes(0).MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Left, Panel1.Top, Panel1.Right, Panel1.Bottom, True)

Dim FHandle As IntPtr
FHandle = FindWindow("MaplestoryClass", Nothing)
SetParent(FHandle, Panel1.Handle)
```

I need to find a way to wait till the Window of the program has shown and then execute the MoveWindow and SetWindowLong event..

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the maple story window?

Comment: That doesn't work because it's disabled

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "programPath";
p.Start();
p.WaitForInputIdle();

SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle);
SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, -16, 0x10000000);
ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 3);
```